# It sounds very wrong to use the present perfect tense with 'while' or with a 'participle phrase', but is it grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I made this sentence a while ago: "the tourist resort has improved in terms of amenities while retaining its trees."

Before I checked theindependent.co.uk for similar sentences, I was so certain I was wrong.

Anyway, I saw this statement on theindependent : "twenty20 cricket has come of age while retaining the idealism and freshness of youth".

So, my main question is: did that news site -- which is supposedly perfect when it comes to grammar -- and I make a grammatical error?

NB: I also saw a similar sentence structure on theguardian, BBC, and business insider.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar of your sentence. Are you suggesting that the improvements to the amenities might have resulted in the loss of the trees?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make that point subtly as development usually entails cutting down trees.

Comment: @onoseshaibu As Kate Bunting says, there is nothing wrong with you original sentence. If you wanted to emphasise the tree situation a bit more you could say "The tourist resort has improved  in terms of amenities without needing to remove any of its trees."